# Android soundpool null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-viewpager, soundpool

I want to play a sound file with soundpool. I am getting error message when I am playing an audio file. ("Unfortunately, the process galeri has stopped" ) How to play short sounds while swiping pages? Thanks.

The code is;

```
package com.example.galeri;
import com.example.galeri.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends  PagerAdapter{
 private static final Context Context = null;
SoundPool snd;
int sescal;
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}


public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    snd = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sescal = snd.load(Context, R.raw.ayna, 1);
    View view = null;

    int resId = 0;       
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.farleft;
        break;
    case 1:
         resId = R.layout.left; // second
         view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
         snd.play(sescal, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1, -1, 1f);
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.middle;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.right;
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.farright;
        break;
    case 5:
        resId = R.layout.other;
        break;
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
    }

   private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context getBaseContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private PagerAdapter findViewById(int myfivepanelpager) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

public static Integer getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Logcat;

```
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at     android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:191)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at com.example.galeri.MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(MyPagerAdapter.java:30)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:692)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:821)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-07 18:37:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(653):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
```

Comment: It would be nice to name your Context member variable mContext instead of Context

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your Context variable which is declared as null and never set.

Then, inside its `load()` method, SoundPool calls `context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resId)` and here you get your NullPointerException.

You can get a valid Context from the `View collection` parameter of your `instantiateItem` method.

So try calling:

```
snd.load(collection.getContext(), R.raw.ayna, 1);
```

Comment: sescal = snd.load(context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resId), R.raw.ayna);     True??